# Why is の placed after the object and before を here?

Tags: particle-の, particle-を, reading-comprehension

Why is の used here after the object in this sentence? Can it be omitted and still have the same meaning “Why didn't you buy the right size?”

> どうしてちょうどいい大きさ**のを**買わなかったの？

Obviously, it's not a verb nominalized. By meaning, it substitutes something like Tシャツ but it not a substitution for a noun like Aいの (e.g., 大きいのです).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than the usage as a verb/adjective nominalizer, the particle の that follows a noun (or noun phrase) acts like a noun, just as if もの is omitted right after the particle. So here ちょうどいい大きさの can be interpreted as ちょうどいい大きさのもの “the one of the right size”

> どうしてちょうどいい大きさを買わなかったの？

The variation where の is also omitted is sometimes heard in daily conversation, but it allows strange interpretation “buy size itself” as well and thus sometimes confusing.

Comment: Rather than 'mono' being omitted, it is perhaps better to view it as 'no' having being omitted, then we can treat other phrases similarly. For example, in this exchange それは健さんの本ですか　—　いいえ、私のです, 私の　is a reduction of 私のの; the sequence のの is obligatorily reduced to の. In the example, ちょうどいい大きさのの　➞　ちょうどいい大きさの.